# How to set default value of spinner with string from Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, arraylist, spinner

I have a form that saves information to Firebase and when the user returns to the form they can edit the information that was saved, because I returned the values as Strings back to the form. Now my problem is that after the user selects an option from the dropdown menu and that selection is saved to the database, how do I return the option saved as the default value in the dropdown menu ?
NB : that different users will have different selections saved

```
    Spinner spinnerCategories;
    String categories[];
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    

    
    spinnerCategories = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategories);
    categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<> 
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,categories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinnerCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code when I save to database:

```
    String businessCategory = spinnerCategories.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

```
reference.child("Businesses").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("businessCategory").setValue(businessCategory);
```

I used this code to return the value:

```
    String businessCategory = snapshot.child("businessCategory").getValue(String.class);
```

Beyond all of this I'm not sure what to do
Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this line of code under my snapshot code and it worked:

```
spinnerCategories
  .setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)spinnerCategories.getAdapter())
  .getPosition(businessCategory));
```

Thanks :)